# DAW In Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

i am trying to create DAW in silverlight but i dont know how to generrate sound of piano,drum and all that instrumnets .. how to Add Music Notation and Play rythm as per Notation .... Can Anyone Please Help Me with this.....

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://www.grape.hu/Pluto/Pluto2.html

Here is a project that may help you to get started:

http://silversynth.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes i am looking to create something like Pluto.... Thanks For The Link But  am  Not able To Find Method to play different Instruments in that .....I am looking to make something that can create a track will all the instruments ... if you find anything please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Also look this:

http://directshow4sl.codeplex.com/

http://salusemediakit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Ai_Boy This is very helpfull but i am looking to play different instruments from my application and save that .. i want to Do that all Using Music notation .... So if u can help me with that....